# Electric power of the light bulbs in a circuit with diodes

Tags: circuit-analysis

Let \$R_1 = 1 \: \Omega, R_2 = 2 \: \Omega, R_3 = 3 \: \Omega, ...R_{10} = 10 \: \Omega\$ be the resistances of the light bulbs depicted in the circuit below and let \$U = 2 \: V\$ be the voltage of the source in the middle.

> **Problem:**
>
> Compute the **eletrical power** \$P\$ of the light bulbs when the
>   diodes' resistances and voltages are neglected. Then do the same when
>   the polarity of the source is inverted.

I just need to know how to attack this problem. My strategy is trying to close the circuit through the light bulb which I'm currently solving.

**My thoughts:**

Let's look at

\$R_3\$:

The current is flowing through \$R_6\$, \$R_4\$ and \$R_4\$, so
$$P_3  = U \cdot I_3 = U \cdot \frac{U}{R_3 + R_4 + R_6} = \frac{4}{13} \: W.$$
Now we can see that the same goes for \$R_6\$ and \$R_4\$, so 
$$P_6 = P_4 = P_3 = \frac{4}{13} \: W.$$

\$R_1:\$

Now I think that if you rearrange \$R_2\$ and \$R_3\$, you can claim that the current goes through \$R_1\$, \$R_2\$ and \$R_3\$, so 
$$P_1 = U \cdot I_1 = U \cdot \frac{U}{R_1 + R_2 + R_3} = \frac{2}{3} \: W.$$
The same goes for \$R_2\$, so:

\$R_2:\$
$$P_2 = P_1 = \frac{2}{3} \: W.$$

\$R_5:\$

The current goes through \$R_6\$, \$R_4\$ and \$R_5\$, but it needs to get to the opposite side, so it goes through \$R_3\$ as well, giving
$$P_5 = U \cdot I_5 = U \cdot \frac{U}{R_3 + R_4 + R_5 + R_6} = \frac{2}{9} \: W.$$

\$R_7 - R_{10}\$:

is just mess for me. I think that the problem is:

- **How do I get the voltage when I'm not on the same parallel?**
- **Should I just continue in the same fashion and try to close the circuit through the light bulb?**

In that way, I'll try to guess \$R_{10}\$:

The current goes through \$R_6\$, \$R_8\$, \$R_{10}\$, \$R_1\$, \$R_2\$ and finally \$R_3\$, so:
$$P_{10} = U \cdot I_{10} = U \cdot \frac{U}{R_1 + R_2 + R_6 + R_8 + R_{10}} = \frac{4}{27} \: W.$$

[image: schematic]

Kirchhoff's law diagram as suggested in the comments:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTghED.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The equations are:

$$I_2 \cdot R_2 + I_3 \cdot R_3 + U = 0$$
$$I_1 \cdot R_1 - I_2 \cdot R_2 = 0$$
$$U + I_3 \cdot R_3 + I_6 \cdot R_6 + I_4 \cdot R_4 = 0$$

and so on...

Comment: Strange example, with 2 V source, the diode's characteristics should not have been neglected. Why do teachers set such unrealistic tasks?

Comment: @TomKuschel I have absolutely no idea. They just want the task not to be trivial but also not too hard. I haven't seen circuits in years. It's for my son who's getting these weird tasks in email since kids don't go to school and I don't want him to do bad because of it. I've done my best right there - I just need a reassurance that I'm not doing something stupid.

Comment: Now after your edit, you switched the polarity of your power source, did you?

Comment: @TomKuschel Oh, the plus is the longer one. I can correct it but shouldn't the current flow from plus to minus? In the problem, it actually goes the opposite way. I need the correct to go downwards.

Comment: I think, best strategy is to unfold the complete circuit with its resistors first, then you see that there are several resistors are in parallel, and you have to calculate the sum of the resistance of your circuit, then you can divide it down...

Comment: yep, the long line of a battery sign is the plus pole.

Comment: Please show us the unfolded circuit diagram for case 1) normal supply and 2) reverse polarity supply. You may remove the diodes.

Comment: @TomKuschel But there are these diods in the way. I thought that when the current crosses a resistor on it's way across the resistor we are solving, we can just add them up because it's in series. At least in my solution I think.

Comment: @TomKuschel I'm not quite sure what you mean by unfolded.

Comment: I don't know if you are a European guy, but try to draw in the voltage arrows - using the kirchhoff's laws, then you see if you can remove a diode or ignore the diode.

Comment: @TomKuschel Did you mean this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106628/discussion-between-tom-kuschel-and-tomashauser).